# Совместимость в IOS SDK

Tags: ios

Я сейчас качаю и устанавливаю ios sdk 6 (ipsw файлы). правильно ли я понимаю, что будет и поддержка старых версий sdk (5,4)?  или для каждой версии ios нужно качать  свой пакет sdk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Там дофига придется пред процессорных if`ов вставлять... сразу пишите под 6.3. В Apple мире при выходе новой СДК, все кто сидят на старом - бомжи. Под них не пишут :)

Comment: значит я правильно сделал что новую версию sdk скачал? только теперь предется смотреть и ифом выбирать какие методы использовать в данной версии sdk (которая у владельца телефона)?

Comment: Как бы да. Просто если ты скачал новую версию доунгрейд делать не вариант. И единственное спасение это проверять версию ios и нужные методы подставлять. И да как говорил aknew симулятором проверяйте все ньюансы... А то может и предпроцесорных ифов не надо.

Comment: Еще могу добавить что собирать стоит всегда последней версией - был у меня в практике случай когда на 6.0 приложение падало просто из-за того что было собрано с сдк 5.1 (конкретные версии могу и спутать, но сути они не меняют), при этом тот же самый код собранный в последнем сдк без проблем работал с 4.3 до 6.0, хотя ифоф там было много.

Answer (score 0):

Поддержка-то будет, но, во-первых, надо будет скачать симмулятор 5.0 и 5.1 отдельно (есть ли там 4.3 уже не помню, кажется нету), во-вторых, придется самому следить за тем когда какие методы появились в сдк - если метода нет скажем в 5, то программа без вопросов скомпилится и запустится на устройстве/симмуляторе, но упадет при попытке вызвать метод